# Website Likebutton admin page not accessible

Tags: button, facebook-like, admin

First, i've read all other related topics but did not found a solution for my problem.

I've many normal Websites with Like buttons integrated but i can't get access to the Adminpage to publish Messages to the Newsfeed of Users who liked the page (i can't see the "Admin Page" Link anywhere).

I have done the [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/) instructions but i does not work for me.

For only a few page i can find the admin [link](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/pages) under  , there i can see the request (*red box*) to migrate my page and everything works fine.

So my question is how to obtain the Admin-Link for my page to get these migrated to normal FB-Pages?

Comment: I think you’ve missed the time window by a bit … that whole change was finished November 7, 2012.

Comment: And now it is not possible to migrate anymore? :(

Comment: Nana-nana-Nope … (Sorry, but just _“No.”_ is considered too short of a comment by SO.)